# Importing Java owlexplanation libraries in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries

I would like to use the owlexplanation API (https://github.com/matthewhorridge/owlexplanation) for a project I am currently working on.
However, I am quite new to Java and I don't know how to import the API into my project.
All the examples I have found suggest to import some JAR files into the project, but there are no JARs in the API I'd like to import.

It sounds it is something extremely easy, but so far I haven't been able to work it out.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you use maven or gradle to build your project?

Comment: No, I don't.  Do I need them?

Comment: Would have made things much simpler, but you can also do without. So you need to download the library and all transitive dependencies manually from the maven repository.

Comment: That worked, thanks very much!